# Logic behind the use of while

Tags: python, while-loop

I have recently approached programming (I'm using Python).
I wanted to understand if someone can explain to me why the "try" is repeated in the loop, while the loop that writes "print (" my house ")" is not repeated.

I am attaching an image for explanatory purposes:

```
def a():
    try:      
        if 3> 0:
           print("This space is occupied, try another!")
           return False
        print("   0  1  2")                  
    except IndexError:
        print("Did you attempt to play a row or column outside the range of 0,1 or 2? (IndexError)")
        return False
    
play = True
while play:
    print ("my house")
    game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]


    game_won = False
    while not game_won:
        print ("a")
        b=a()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are *two* loops, and the inner one never terminates (since you never update `game_won`, so you never move on to the second iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: why is the "try" repeated then?
I can't understand why Python go back to iterating that too.

Comment: @UmbertoManzalini why do you think it *shouldn't* be repeated? Your condition is `not game_won`, and right above it you assign `game_won = False`, so `not game_won` will be true. Where did you expect that condition to be false? That loop will keep repeating until that condition is false, or your `break` out of the loop (or something raises an error, or you exit the program entirely, etc.)

Comment: I suspect you intended to use `game_won = a()` so that the loop would terminate when `a` returns `True`. At the moment, though, `a` *never* returns `True`, so the loop would still continue indefinitely.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not clear.
I understand why only the second of the two while loops is repeated.
However, I don't understand why "print (" This space is occupied, try another! ")" Which stands in "try:" is repeated.

Comment: Why would it not? `a` still runs multiple times, and the `try` statement is part of that function, and `3 > 0` is always going to be true.

Comment: so the first while is not considered part of the "a" function?
if the function is repeated I would expect to repeat the first while as well, being part of it in my consideration.
repeating the function, I imagine starting from the beginning and then finding the first while too.

Comment: Neither loop is part of `a`. `a` is *called* inside the second loop, and each time you call `a`, you execute its body starting at the top of the *function*. Only the code *indented* relative to the `def` statement itself is part of the function definition. In this case, `a` consists only of the `try/except` statement. `play = True` is the first line of code *following* the `def` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understand

Answer (score 0):

You have two indefinite loops. The inner loop that terminates on predicate; `not game_won` the logic in the inner loop continues indefinitely without returning to the outer context because at no point within the loop do you set `game_won=True`.

```
def a():
    try:      
        if 3> 0:
           print("This space is occupied, try another!")
           return False
        print("   0  1  2")                  
    except IndexError:
        print("Did you attempt to play a row or column outside the range of 0,1 or 2? (IndexError)")
        return False
    
play = True
while play:
    print ("my house")
    game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]


    game_won = False
    while not game_won:
        print ("a")
        b=a()
        if 1==1:
            break  # This will cause exit.
```

Comment: Do you mean "infinite"?

Comment: They are indefinite without a terminating code path.

Comment: I understand what you are telling me.
The fact is that by setting "b = a ()" in addition to the inner loop, the "try" part is also repeated.
I'm interested in understanding why this happens (while the external "while" is rightly skipped)

Comment: A loop that never ends is called an "infinite" loop, *not* an "indefinite" loop. "Indefinite" means "lasting for an unknown or unstated length of time."

Comment: Everything inside 'while not game_won' repeats infinitely. @UmbertoManzalini

Comment: Exactly. It's an "infinite" loop, not an "indefinite" loop.

Comment: I know, I am referring to the while loop which is an indefinite loop. It is confusing because I then refer to the loop using standard English meaning of indefinitely. @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica

Comment: so the Try part is considered inside the second loop?
but it wouldn't be if I don't write "b = a ()", right?

Answer (score 0):

first the while play loop will start and it will go on until while not game_won loop and since not game_won is True it will start that loop and wont go out until not game_won is False

Comment: But the output is something like this:

"my house
a
This space is occupied, try another!
a
This space is occupied, try another!
a..."

While I would expect:
"a
a
a..."


I understand that it happens by "b = a ()", but not the reason.

Comment: well then just: while True: print('a')

Answer (score 0):

```
def a():
    try:      
        if 3> 0:
           print("This space is occupied, try another!")
           return false
        print("   0  1  2")                  
    except IndexError: # You never reach this point because 3 > 0: is the same as just putting if 1==1 it always reads as a true statement
        print("Did you attempt to play a row or column outside the range of 0,1 or 2? (IndexError)")
        return False
    
play = True
while play: # 1. while True gets executed on the first iteration
    print ("my house")
    game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]


    game_won = False
    while not game_won: # 2. you get stuck here and is the same as While True unless you specify when the game is won
        b=a()
```

basically you are stuck in the second loop only calling function a() entering the try: part of your code multiple times you can see this to help you identify whats happening by adding a loop counter in function a

```
i=0
def a():
    global i
    try:      
        if 3> 0:
            print("This space is occupied, try another!")
            i=i+1
            print(f"you have ran a() {i} times")
            return False
        print("   0  1  2")
    except IndexError: # You never reach this point because 3 > 0: is the same as just putting if 1==1 it always reads as a true statement
        print("Did you attempt to play a row or column outside the range of 0,1 or 2? (IndexError)")
        return False
```

Maybe this logic will help you understand the how the code gets executed a little better

```
def a():
    x=4*4 #2 just some math that results in 16
    return x #3 you return x so it can be accessed outside of the function if you did not add this when print(b) is called it will result in a None type
while True:
    b=a() # 1. ) this calls the function a() and stores the result in the variable b
    print(int(b))
```

Comment: ok very clear.
But why does adding "b = a ()" make me repeat the part of "print (" This space is occupied, try another! ")"?

Comment: when you assign the b to a() it calls that function with b=a() you execute the function a()

Comment: I just added to my answer if you can see how python executes functions when assigned to a variable